# How to customize ring size in sunburst chart using R?

Tags: sunburst-diagram

Please find the sunburst chart created using R. There are 6 rings in total. How to customize the width of each ring? For example, first, third and fifth ring to be of bigger size when compared to the even numbered rings.
[Sunburst Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ID34m.jpg)

Appreciate your help and thanks in advance!!